# How do I prevent my regex from matching a trailing quote in a string?

Tags: regex

I am rejigging some urls that have been defined in javascript:

```
var x = "http:\/\/example.com\/test.aspx?v=12.1&x=2&p=3";
var y = "http:\/\/example.com\/test.aspx?v=92.1&x=2&p=4";
```

My regex to capture the domain part, the path and the querystring into a capture group works great:

```
(http:\\/\\/example.com\\/)([0-9a-zA-Z-\\\/\._]+)([\?]?)(.+)`
```

However the sand in the vaseline is that the last double quote is being matched as well. How do a stop matching just before the end quote?

As it happens this is for IIS7's UrlRwriter so I can't use any code to strip the end quote off.

Comment: Something that just occurred to me: Are these strings all using double-quotes? Or could some be using single quotes? Meaning are they all `var foo = "bar";` or could some of them be `var foo = 'bar';`?

Comment: @justin - I have no access to the source code that injects the javascript into the page, but from what I can tell all of the strings are in double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you don't allow quotes in the URL body, so you could just change the `(.+)` to `([^"]+)`.

**Edit:** It occurs to me you might need to allow for `"` or `'`, so you could just change the above to `([^"']+)`. If you want to be more thorough, you can go with

`([^"']+)(http:\\/\\/example.com\\/)([0-9a-zA-Z-\\\/\._]+)([\?]?)(.+?)\1`

...and ignore the first capture group. This way, it takes everything up to the next matching quote. That's probably unnecessary, though. I can't imagine that you'd want to allow `'` or `"` in your URL string, but the `.` already matches several characters that aren't supposed to be in URLs, so I thought I'd leave it up to you.

Comment: out of interest and further to your question asking about whether there could be single quoted strings, how would you handle that? I tried `(([^"]+)|([^']+))` but that doesn't work so well with mixed "" and '' strings.

Comment: +1 ha....you must've just posted that as I added my last comment. Excellent that works a treat.

Comment: @Kev - Glad to hear it! BTW check my edit, I accidentally had `[^"]` instead of `[^"']` for a second there. C&P error on my part.

Answer (score 2):

instead of matching anything one or more times `.+` try matching anything not a quote one or more times:

```
[^"]+
```

The `[]` creates a character class, and the '^' means not .. or a negated character class. This will literally match anything not a quote.

Comment: depends on the language your using; for regex itself however the " doesnt need to be escaped; ie. in perl `/[^"]+/` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yeah, I misread, sorry. I thought he was also quoting his regex string. N/m.